# How to prevent an element to get pushed down by window resize?

Tags: html, css

My goal is to prevent "hello" span from being pushed down by window resize.

http://jsfiddle.net/5MjNL/5/

**HTML**

```
<div id='main'>
    <div class='container'>
        <input type='text' class='input-field'></input>
        <span class='foo'>hello</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main
{
    border:1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
.input-field
{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width:70%;
}
```

In jsfiddle, if you drag the browser window to reduce the size horizontally, at some point, the SPAN containing "hello" text will get pushed down.

How do I set my style so that only text field width is reduced?

Comment: "Hello" goes down at the point when browser size goes less than 200px. The smallest resolution on devices is 320px width (phones) so I don't see what is the problem here. Your code works fine until it reaches less than approx. 200px;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `white-space: nowrap` to the `.container:

```
.container {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Or try using flexbox (this covers old and new syntax):

```
.container {
    display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
    display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option can be to, specify the min-width that you would like and define overflow as auto,

This will make sure that the div is still fluid and expands, but stops contracting where the page structure starts getting messed up, and the user can scroll

http://jsfiddle.net/5MjNL/6/

```
#main
{
    border:1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    min-width:300px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto; 

}

.input-field
{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width:70%;
}
.foo{

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want this behavior you might consider using percentages. You could, but don't have to, do something like:

```
#main{
  width:/*percentage of choice here*/;
}
.contianer{
  width:/*percentage of choice here*/;
}
.input-field{
  width:/*percentage of choice here*/;
}
.foo{
  width:/*not a percentage width here*/;
}
```